# postfix as SMTP Gateway

Tags: configuration, email, postfix

I have around 10 servers and all of them are running Postfix for web-hosting based clients. so I can only judge outgoing sender domain but not the destination domains. It can be anything.

now, I have placed a master SMTP Gateway on top of all these Postfix Servers and routed all other servers through the master SMTP Gateway. ( reason being to avoid handling 10 postfix servers and also hiding their information to avoid DDOS attacked, I am hiding as much information as possible by doing header checks rewriting)

Question:

Do I need to configure the DKIM on the Master SMTP Gateway server or on all individual servers...

Its a CentOS setup and I need some guidance on setting on the DKIM so that all outgoing emails are being signed and accepted by big emails guns like Gmail, Yahoo, and hotmail etc.

Comment: I doubt you manage DNS for all those domains and DKIM requires DNS record.

Comment: I can manage DNS for all my clients hosted with me. No problem with that.